# How do I remove the first 100 words from a string?

Tags: javascript

I only want to remove the first 100 words and keep whats remaining from the string.

The code I have below does the exact opposite:

```
   var short_description = description.split(' ').slice(0,100).join(' ');
```

Comment: Did you look at some [doco for `.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)?

Comment: I did wrong in my answer, but [this page will help you](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2159-Using-Slice-Substring-And-Substr-In-Javascript.htm)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - No, that page is about the _String_ functions. OP needs the _Array_ `.slice()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn ok that is the reason my answer was wrong, thanks :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remove the first argument:

```
var short_description = description.split(' ').slice(100).join(' ');
```

Using `slice(x, y)` will give you elements from `x` to `y`, but using `slice(x)` will give you elements from `x` to the end of the array. (note: this will return the empty string if the description has less than 100 words.)

[Here is some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

You could also use a regex:

```
var short_description = description.replace(/^([^ ]+ ){100}/, '');
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
^      beginning of string
(      start a group
[^ ]   any character that is not a space
+      one or more times
       then a space
)      end the group. now the group contains a word and a space.
{100}  100 times
```

Then replace those 100 words with nothing. (note: if the description is less than 100 words, this regex will just return the description unchanged.)

Comment: Thanks for this, which option is better in terms of performance?

Comment: @user971824 You could try doing a test at http://jsperf.com (I am on a smartphone now so I can't), but I'm guessing the difference would be very small.

Comment: 2 remarks, please correct me if I'm wrong but 1- your regexp does not consider "don't" as 2 words, and 2- it won't work if the string is less than 100 words (in which case I assume it should return empty string)

Comment: @Sebas 1- You think "don't" is two words? If English is not your first language then I understand, but "don't" is a single word... 2- The first code snippet returns empty string if the string is less than 100 words; the second returns the string unchanged. I'll edit that into my answer, thanks

Comment: 1- Hmm, for some reasons I though so. What about dashes? Sorry if I've been unclear, my point was actually to advise using the \w character class that is made for word counts instead of splitting by spaces.

Comment: As a note, when I ran the JSPref mentioned, it showed that the regex example was 74% faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
//hii i am getting result using this function   


 var inputString = "This is           file placed  on           Desktop"
    inputString = removeNWords(inputString, 2)
    console.log(inputString);
    function removeNWords(input,n) {
      var newString = input.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
      var x = newString.split(" ")
      return x.slice(n,x.length).join(" ")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var short_description = description.split(' ').slice(100).join(' ');
```

Comment: you can do slice(100) to go from 100th element to the end of the array as well.

Comment: `.slice(100,description.length-1)` will leave off the last word.

Comment: Actually, I was right that this answer was wrong (pre-edit), but I was wrong about the result. I thought you were using one less than the length of the _array,_ which would leave off the last word - but you were using one less than the length of the _string,_ which has no relationship to the number of words at all...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes you are, it worked because,array length is more than the length of splitted content..I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is doing the opposite, is that slice returns the selected elements (in this case, the first one hundred) and returns them in it's own array. To get all of the elements after one hundred, you would have to do something like description.slice(100) to get the split array properly, and then your own join to merge back the array.